# Customizing the Vendor Page on Marketify Theme Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, vendor

I am using the Marketify theme on Wordpress and want to customize the vendor page. I want it so that everything is centered. At the top is the featured image of the vendor. Below would be the name of the vendor. Below that would be the author's subscription. Then below that would be the list of products the vendor had.

I tried reaching out to Marketify's support but they told me to just get a freelancer pretty much.

[image]

I appreciate any and all help! This issue needs to be addressed because there are no tutorials or any documentation on how to customize the vendor page on the Marketify theme.